# OrderBy extension method not found

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have created a function within a class of one project and moved it to a class of a different project. In the first project everything compiles but in the second project I get the following error message:
... does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type

The extension OrderBy of List does not exist in the second project but does exist in the first one. The same .NET framework is set in both projects. I am not sure what else I should look for.

Can you please suggest what to do ?

Thanks,
Paul Feher

Answer (score 17):

Does your second project have the required namespace imported `using System.Linq;`